# Converting from Planck units to Hartree units

Tags: electromagnetism, units, si-units

I am trying to include an analytical formula into a numerical program. In Planck units, the expression looks like this: $\frac{A}{B}$, where $A$ is in $m$ while $B$ is in $eV^{-1}$.

If we go to SI units, we have  $\frac{Ae}{B \hbar c}$, where $e$ is the electric charge. In Hartree units, this give us  $\frac{Ae\alpha}{B}$, where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant, since in Hatree units $\hbar =1$ and $c=\frac{1}{\alpha}$. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think Planck units have anything to do with the unit of energy (or mass) called an *"electron-volt"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Converting from Planck units to Hartree units" is an ill-defined problem, because there are many SI quantities that correspond to a given Planck-unit quantity.

However, your problem is not quite what's in the title, because you have already identified which SI quantity you want to convert to [Hartree atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units), namely $q=Ae/\hbar c B$, where $A$ is a length and $B$ is an inverse energy. And, to do this, you (i) set $\hbar=1$, (ii) set $e=1$, and (iii) use the correct value of the speed of light, $c=1/\alpha$.

Thus, in Hartree atomic units, you would have $q=\alpha A/B$.